# MVC3 unobtrusive validation - how can I see validation failed if the inputs are off the screen?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a wizard in MVC3 that scrolls through multiple pages before reaching a confirmation page with a submit button.

My problem is, when there is a validation failure in one of the previous pages of the wizard, the issue is not visible when clicking the submit button; all the validation messages are in hidden divs.

How can I tap into the validation on clicking the submit so that I can show a dialog that says "There are one or more problems with the form submission" or something like that when validation fails?

Comment: Only a suggestion, would it be easier to trigger validation per "page", not letting the user continue to the next page if there is an issue or would that model not fit?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl That makes maintaining the data across multiple redirects very unwieldy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically add each form for validation and remove it when done validating and no longer in focus. I'm on phone here so forgive the brevity as I can add more details once at computer.
If all you want to do is show a message then hook into form post and check if the form is valid via form.validate() or .valid()

For more control 
http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introducing-hooks-in-the-jquery-form-validation-engine-plugin/

[How to hook into error of jQuery validate unobtrusive in MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494008/how-to-hook-into-error-of-jquery-validate-unobtrusive-in-mvc-3)

I do think this may be best done through Ajax and multiple requests and persist each stage somewhere (could use cache or db)  prior to submitting for the final save.